# What is `Kashmir Series of texts and studies`?

Tags: scripture, kashmiri-shaivism

All the Kashmirir Shaivite scriptures are originally (in Sanskrit) found with a prefix `Kashmir Series of texts and studies`. What is the reason behind this naming? It seems some organization (probably public) have/had undertaken the work to publish Kashmiri Scriptures in bulk. Is that so? And my another question is what are all those scriptures have been published under the same title? Can we get a list of those scriptures which have been published so far under the same name?

Comment: Kashmir Series of Texts and Studies is not the same series referred to in the answer. It has actually published many many Tantras For e.g it has first published the Malinivijaya in the 1920s.

Comment: Yes @Rickross you can answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series is so named because of the publishers and which is "The Archaeological and Research Department, Srinagar, Kashmir.

[image]
[image]

The above images are from Vol 1 of the series as found on Archive.com.

As regards, a complete list of scriptures, they had published, then I know of many such Tantrik scriptures but may be can't give a full list.

So, for the time being it's a partial answer.

**UPDATE:**

I still can not give you the entire list of scriptures they have made available. But I can give at least the name of some of them.

Like:

Brihannila Tantram (1941), Devirahasya Tantram (1937), Gandharva Tantram (1944), Malinivijayottara Tantram (1922), Netra Tantram (1926), Tantraloka, Paratrisika, Shivasutravimarshini, Vijyanabhairabha Tantram ..

See the following images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, as you can see the Netra Tantram is their publication no-46, Malinivijayotttara Tantram the 37th. So, they have at least 46 volumes of that series. Needless to say a huge venture.

Comment: Wow, Maharaja of Kashmir was responsible!

Comment: Yes and this is an exceptional major work done to save the Tantras. This is the only such effort that is done outside of Bengal. @Rohit.

Comment: Please try to enumerate the works under the same publication.

Comment: better if we get at least list of 46

Comment: But right now I don't have the list of even 46 of them.. will be on the look out @Rohit.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the SUNY (State University of New York) Press' series:  [SUNY series in the Shaiva Traditions of Kashmir](http://www.sunypress.edu/Searchadv.aspx?IsSubmit=true&pagesize=-1&Orderby=1&CategoryID=6995)

Comment: Thanks dear. Good to know about this series. but I think the given title in the question belong to Kashmir state govn or Maharaja before partition. not sure.

Comment: You can wait before accepting.